# Best place to initialize Mongoid in a ruby gem

Tags: ruby, mongodb, rubygems, mongoid

I am building a ruby gem which will require communication with MongoDB. I am using Mongoid as my client driver and I am curious what the best practice is in as far as initializing within the context of a ruby gem. I need to run the following somewhere appropriate:

```
Mongoid.load!("path/to/your/mongoid.yml", :production)
```

The question is where is the best place to do this in a ruby gem in order to ensure my MongoDB connection is available throughout my code?

Comment: I'd use something like a `MyGem::Connection` object that specifically deals with connecting to the Mongoid DB. Even better is a constant. For every class/function that uses the connection object, I would pass in the connection object explicitly. That way, I don't have to use a global variable. Is that what you're looking for? or something else more specific?

Comment: I'm looking for a more generic response such as the best place when building a rubygem to put the connection information to, when to connect to the database and how to manage the connection all within the context of the gem itself.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, the best practice is that you don't do it at all.

What happens if consumers of your rubygem are already using Mongoid elsewhere in their application? It wouldn't make sense for you (from within a rubygem dependency they're using) to initialize an additional client instance/mongoid session when you could use an existing one.

I would let your users manage their own connection and build your library so that it knows how to set itself up provided that it's handed a functioning database connection.

For example, you could do something like this:

```
# for rails apps, in config/initializers
YourGem.configure do |config|
  config.client = mongoid_client_instance
end

# for use outside rails
my_instance = YourGem.new(mongoid_client_instance)
```

In cases like this, it's best to avoid making assumptions about how they want to initialize external dependencies or forcing any decisions on them.

Answer (score 0):

I would simply document the setup information within your Gem / Repository and add Mongoid to your .gemspec as a dependency.

Gems shouldn't be intrusive and configuration should be obvious, manageable and well documented.